# How does 4ext recovery backup works

Tags: recovery-mode

Does it read the partition and copy it bit by bit to some file?

Comment: Care to explain downvotes?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I might explain: your question is most likely considered "low quality". You don't give much details what you're talking about – e.g. what is "4ext recovery backup"? Without knowing that, the question cannot be answered. Backup apps are different: some work on block level, some on file level; some do full backups, some only cover parts. And depending on that, their algorithms differ as well: those working on block-level do exactly what you describe, others don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backup of *any* partition works by simply copying an image of it to a file. This is accomplished by using the simple command `dd if=<path to device eg. sdcard (/dev/block)> of=<path to file to backup to>`.

The resulting file is (as already written) an image of the original partition which can be explored as a drive on any OS, which features mounting an image to a drive (primarily any linux distro).